# How to insert multiple rows into MySQL table (with auto increment) and skip duplicates?

Tags: mysql, sql, r

I have a MySQL `table1` in which:

- `id` is auto incremented
- `A`, `B`, `C` are NON-UNIQUE

  ```
  dbReadTable(con, "test1")

  id A B C
  1  a 5 A
  2  b 4 B
  3  c 3 C
  4  a 2 A
  5  b 1 B
  ```

I want to add new rows to `table1` from this data frame `df`:

```
df <- data.frame(A = c("a", "b", "d", "e"),
                 B = c(2, 1, 6, 7),
                 C = c("A", "B", "D", "E"))
df

  A B C
  a 2 A
  b 1 B
  d 6 D
  e 7 E
```

...but of course skip duplicated rows (first two of `df`), to get updated `table1` like that:

```
dbReadTable(con, "test1")
id A B C
 1 a 5 A
 2 b 4 B
 3 c 3 C
 4 a 2 A
 5 b 1 B
 6 d 6 D
 7 e 7 E
```

`id` does not have to be sequential of course (but it will be nice if it can be).

I was doing it by downloading entire `table1` and anti-joining with `df` to find and insert new records only back to `table1`, but it doesn't look like a good solution. My `table1` and `df` are ~100k/~30k rows (and ~10 variables), respectively.

How to do that?
I'm using `R` and `DBI`, but pure SQL will be also great to have.
Thanks guys!

Comment: Is this just a SQL `union` or is there more to it? E.g. `select A,B,C from test1 union select A,B,C from df`

Comment: I don't follow the logic for adding new values.  Can you describe the logic behind the _output_ table you eventually want to have?  It might be easier to just generate such a table (of some number of rows) from scratch.

Comment: @thelatemail The OP seems to want some auto increment behavior on the `B` column.  But the other details are not clear to me.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - a plain old union on A/B/C gives the exact result minus the `id` column from what I can tell. `a/2/a` and `b/1/b` are dropped when `union`ed because they are already exactly in the base table. Regenerating the `id` counter would be the only drama.

Comment: What I want to do is to ADD `df` to `table1` , not select non-duplicates (as  add to database).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Sorry for confusion, `B` has nothing to do with AI, it can be replaced with characters as well. I just want to update `table1` with the values from `df`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to not insert values where the A and C values match an existing table1 row.  I would use a temporary table for that, first inserting into the temporary table, then inserting into table1 only the appropriate rows:

```
create temporary table df (A varchar(1), B int, C varchar(1));
insert into df values ('a',2,'A'),('b',1,'B'),('d',6,'D'),('e',7,'E');
insert into table1 (A,B,C) select df.* from df left join table1 using (A,C) where table1.id is null;
```

An index on (A,C) in table1 will make this efficient.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=d330b72e13021a191564f78eba2091fe)

Comment: Cool! that is exactly what I needed. I didn't know about temporary tables :) Thanks

Comment: Your solution works great, but fails when NAs are introduced - then records are duplicated again. How to solve it?

Comment: ok, solved it using `ON ... <=> ...` operator, but maybe there is a better way to do that?

Comment: you mean when A or C is null it would add duplicates of those?  yes, just use `<=>`.  or `from df where not exists (select 1 from table1 where (table1.A,table1.B) <=> (df.A,df.C))`